# git confusion - cloning a repo is returning a past version

Tags: git

Im having some confusion with my git usage. 
I cloned a repo from one comp to the other, and the new clone is the state of the original that was active some time ago. So its cloning a past version. 
when I do 'git log -n1' to see what the latest commit info of the new repo (the clone) it matches the original repo that I cloned (the latest commit info), so thats confusing me even more since git is indicating that both are the latest versions.
Im using git 1.5.4.3 on ubuntu server. 
any ideas

thanks

Comment: Could you give the comands you typed on every computer? I might be easier to follow what happende.

Comment: sure
on the 2nd comp I did :  $git clone repoURL
and then to check that the right SHA1 signature is there, of the clone repo, I did :  $git log -n1       
I just compared that hash on both machines and they match... so it seems that the repo is in the same state on both of them

Comment: It should be `git log -n1 origin`, otherwise you are listing commits on your current branch, which is probably 'master', and unless you do `git pull` being on it, the 'master' branch wouldn't be up to date wrt remote changes

Answer (score 2):

First make sure all changes are committed on the remote repository.

```
git add .
git commit -m "my commit message"
```

Running `git status` should show no uncommitted changes.

Then on your local copy try running

```
git pull origin master #or whatever branch you're on
```

You can list branches by running

```
git branch -a
```

The `-a` shows local branches and those from the repository you cloned from.

It you need to switch to another branch on the from the remote repository you need to set up a local tracking branch first.  The command will look something like:

```
git branch --track my_branch origin/my_branch
git checkout my_branch
```

When in doubt run

```
git pull origin master #or whatever branch you're on
```

This would bring your local working copy up to date with the remote repository.

Comment: ok so 'git branch -a' on the original repo is showing only the master branch (* master), while on the new clone repo its showing (* master\n origin/HEAD \n origin/master). Honestly Im not sure what this indicates. 
I just did 'git pull origin master' and its telling me that its up to date... so I think that its the original thats somehow not in correct state, or should I say I think that the repo checked in is not representing the working directory state... 
on the original repo every time I do a "git commit -m 'test'" it submits the latest changes as if it sees them for the first time...

Comment: You may have "unstaged" changes on your remote repo.  On the remote repo run `git add .` to stage all changes.  Then `git commit -m "my message"`.  Then try running `git pull origin master` again from your local repo.

Comment: not thats not it, been doing that on the local repo... even when I dont change anything doing 'git add .' & 'git commit -m "test"' keeps recommiting the changes as if it sees them for the first time... instead it should tell me 'nothing to commit' or something of that sort. I have a feeling that has something to do with it

Answer (score 0):

Are you on the same branch as the other repo?

(you get master by default, and newer commits in other branch aren't possibly hidden until you switch.)

Comment: I didnt create any branches on either, so they're both working with the master branch. when I cloned it creates a from scratch repo so I couldnt create branches even if I wanted to
thanks

Answer (score 0):

That could possibly happen if you have inconsistent treating of newlines (`core.autocrlf`).

Make a simple change (add a line into one of your files).

Paste here what `git diff`, `git status`, `cat .git/config` say on and what is the exact output of `git commit -am "test"`